# Animate line wrapping of inline-block elements on content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container with a fixed width and `overflow: auto;` set.
It contains multiple items (`display: inline-block;`), also with fixed dimensions.
So if the container has enough children, the items will wrap around and create a grid-like pattern.

Now I dynamically remove children from the beginning and want to animate the *position change* of the items that are filling up the freed space and moving up from the start of a line to the end of the line above.

```js
var counter = 1;

document.getElementById("additem").onclick = function() {
 var item = document.createElement("div");
  item.innerText = counter;
  counter++;
 document.getElementById('container').appendChild(item);
}

document.getElementById("removeitem").onclick = function() {
 document.getElementById('container').removeChild(
    document.getElementById('container').children[0]
 );
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 280px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#container > div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="additem">add item</button>
<button id="removeitem">remove item</button>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

EDIT: I am also able to use jQuery to accomplish this behaivor.

Comment: Replace the removed element with an invisible element of the same size, then dynamically shrink that removed element to zero width.

Comment: @Pete thanks, I updated my question.

Comment: @Blazemonger This will cause to animate only the items in the first row to be animated, the following div will still instantly wrap to the previous line.

Comment: You could use jQuery to animate the width to 0 and then remove the hidden element: https://jsfiddle.net/eaLaxvvv/6/

Comment: @Caedmon Yes, but this won't work if I want to remove an element other than the last one: https://jsfiddle.net/eaLaxvvv/7/
You can still see the divs teleporting between lines.

Comment: True, how about using something like this, I've used it in the past and it worked nicely: https://packery.metafizzy.co

Comment: If you want to animate elements moving from the start of one line to the end of another, you'll need a whole new JavaScript-based solution.

Comment: @Blazemonger Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I agree with @Blazemonger that this requires a reasonably complex JS solution that takes many cases into account. If you want to create this, maybe you are better off using some library (if one exists) or designing the aglorithm on paper (maybe there's a StackExchange site to help you with designing it?) and implementing it yourself. Asking for it here, without any idea of where to start, will probably not really help you too much, except for simple solutions like the one I have provided, which seem to not suit your needs, as you need a more robust one.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably clean solution is to use an inline style that sets the removed element's `opacity` to `0`, accompanied by a `transition` and a `setTimeout` timed to run as soon as the transition finishes, effectively fading out the element and then sliding everything else into place. Here's a quick snippet I put together:

```js
var counter = 1;

document.getElementById("additem").onclick = function() {
  var item = document.createElement("div");
  item.innerText = counter;
  counter++;
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(item);
}

document.getElementById("removeitem").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').children[0].setAttribute('style', 'opacity: 0');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('container').removeChild(
      document.getElementById('container').children[0]
    )
  }, 300);

}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 280px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#container>div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button id="additem">add item</button>
<button id="removeitem">remove item</button>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will still cause all other items to switch their position immediately, which is what I want to avoid.